# how to get the marks in ‘Math’ of ‘English’ topper for each class in mysql for student result data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I need to find the marks in ‘Math’, of ‘English’ topper for each class in MySQL for student result data.

**Output schema:** class, roll_no, math_marks

(Here expected result image not exact answer)

[image]

my table is as,

```
CREATE TABLE resultdata 
(
  class TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  roll_number TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  subjects VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
  marks TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO resultdata(class,roll_number,subjects,marks) VALUES
(8, 1, 'math', 98),
(8, 1,'english', 88),
(8, 1,'science', 96),
(8, 1,'computer', 94),
(8, 2,'math', 78),
(8, 2,'english', 89),
(8, 2,'science', 87),
(8, 2,'computer', 99),
(9, 1,'math', 90),
(9, 1,'english', 85),
(9, 1,'science', 85),
(9, 1,'computer', 85),
(9, 2,'math', 95),
(9, 2,'english', 30),
(9, 2,'science', 40),
(9, 2,'computer', 80),
(10, 1,'math', 85),
(10, 1,'english', 90),
(10, 1,'science', 65),
(10, 1,'computer', 45),
(10, 2,'math', 50),
(10, 2,'english', 95),
(10, 2,'science', 65),
(10, 2,'computer', 85),
(10, 3,'math', 51),
(10, 3,'english', 61),
(10, 3,'science', 71),
(10, 3,'computer', 81);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the english topper that has the max mark in math:

```
SELECT n.class as class, r.roll_number, max(r2.marks) as mathmarks, n.maxmarks as 
englishmarks
FROM
resultdata r,
resultdata r2,
(SELECT class, max(marks) as maxmarks
FROM
resultdata
WHERE subjects='english'
GROUP BY class) n
WHERE n.class=r.class AND n.maxmarks=r.marks AND r.subjects='english'
AND r2.class=r.class AND r2.subjects='math' AND r2.roll_number=r.roll_number
GROUP BY n.class, n.maxmarks, r.roll_number;
```

If you want al the toppers:

```
SELECT n.class as class, r.roll_number, r2.marks as mathmarks, n.maxmarks as englishmarks
FROM
resultdata r,
resultdata r2,
(SELECT class, max(marks) as maxmarks
FROM
resultdata
WHERE subjects='english'
GROUP BY class) n
WHERE n.class=r.class AND n.maxmarks=r.marks AND r.subjects='english'
AND r2.class=r.class AND r2.subjects='math' AND r2.roll_number=r.roll_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

This question intrigued me - the requirement to have the mark for Mathematics for the class (regardless of role) which (who?) obtained the best mark in English.

I decided to go one better and obtain the results for all subjects for the best in class in English - fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6216daa11af93d9135ea055060ddddcb).

The SQL:

```
SELECT t1.class, t1.roll_number,
       t1.sci_mark,
       t1.comp_mark,
       t1.math_mark,
       t1.eng_mark
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    class, 
    roll_number,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subjects = 'math'
      THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS math_mark,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subjects = 'english'
      THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS eng_mark,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subjects = 'science'
      THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS sci_mark,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subjects = 'computer'
      THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS comp_mark
  FROM resultdata
  GROUP BY class, roll_number
) AS t1
JOIN 
(
  SELECT class, MAX(marks) AS maxmark
  FROM resultdata
  WHERE subjects = 'english'
  GROUP BY class
) AS t2
ON 
  t1.class = t2.class AND 
  t1.eng_mark = t2.maxmark
ORDER BY class, eng_mark DESC;
```

Result:

```
class   roll_number sci_mark    comp_mark   math_mark   eng_mark
    8             2       87           99          78         89
    9             1       85           85          90         85
   10             2       65           85          50         95
```

A glance at the other solution [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253502/34007) shows that it matches on the Mathematics score for the highest English mark. Inspection shows that it works for the two other subjects (Science and Computers) also. As pointed out here [MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function](https://www.tarynpivots.com/post/how-to-rotate-rows-into-columns-in-mysql/), but I got this technique from that site.